# Stable presentable categories as module categories

Tags: infinity-categories, stable-homotopy, homotopy-theory, gn.general-topology

There is a theorem of Schwede and Shipley which classifies categories of modules over an A<sub>∞</sub> ring spectrum as those stable presentable (∞,1)-categories with a compact generator.  Suppose I allow my A<sub>∞</sub> rings to "have many objects", that is, I consider categories of the form Fun<sub>Sp</sub>(I<sup>op</sup>, Sp) where Sp is the category of spectra, I is a small Sp-enriched category (in some appropriate sense) and Fun<sub>sp</sub> denotes the category of Sp-enriched functors.  Is there a classification of which stable presentable categories can be obtained in this way?  Is it possible that *all* stable presentable categories are of this form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the abstract of http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0108143 (Schwede & Shipley, *Classification of Stable Model Categories*), they deal with the case of stable model categories (=stable presentable (∞,1)-categories, I suppose) which have a set of compact generators, and show they are the same as model categories of functors from spectral-enriched categories.

(Edited, in the light of Reid's comment, to include the hypothesis of *compact* generators.)

Comment: I think that "has a set of generators" is implied by "presentable", right?

Comment: Ah.  I should have said "compact generators", as that appears the condition Schwede-Shipley require.  So "presentable" implies "set of generators", but "compact generators" is much more special.

Comment: I don't have a ready example in the case where you drop the hypothesis of compactness.  If you form the localization of spectra with respect to a homology theory E, the localization L_E(S) of the sphere spectrum is a generator for this stable homotopy theory, but in general L_E(S) is not compact.  But this doesn't preclude the existence of some other compact generator, and that actually happens in some cases, e.g., E= a Morava K-theory.

Comment: Corollary B.13 of the reference [HS99] gives examples of what I presume are stable presentable categories without any nonzero compact objects.